# Rails 5 - Problem with Umlaute and parameterize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I work on Rails 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.5.1. At some point, I found an issue when I expected my array-of-string constant to contain some string but it didn't. Turned out the problem was related to German Umlaute characters (öäü).

So I have the constant defined like the following:

```
# coding: utf-8
# frozen_string_literal: true
class MyClass
  module MyModule
    MY_CONSTANT = [
      'Breite in mm',
      'Höhe in mm',
      'Länge in mm'
    ].map(&:parameterize).freeze
  end
end
```

I expect the constant to look like `["breite-in-mm", "hoehe-in-mm", "laenge-in-mm"]`

But instead it's stored as `["breite-in-mm", "hohe-in-mm", "lange-in-mm"]`. You see, "ö" has been converted to "o" instead of "oe". Same for "ä". Now it's "a", not "ae".

It works this way on production, in RSpec tests and even when I start Rails console and call this constant. But when I define a new constant from Rails console using the very same code, the strings are being successfully converted to what I expect, i.e. `["breite-in-mm", "hoehe-in-mm", "laenge-in-mm"]`

I could easily get rid of this `parameterize` method and just type in the strings as I need them. Maybe I will have to do that. But I'm really curious about why all this is happening and couldn't find an answer by myself.

So thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Holger Just for your great answer. It seems to be correct except it only works for Rails 6.0.0. So I'm going to post the one for Rails 5.2.3 which I'm using on my project.

Unfortunately in Rails 5 `parameterize` method does not accept the `locale` argument yet. This will be possible only in Rails 6.

But still, as mentioned in Holger Just's answer, `parameterize` method relies on `transliterate` method which does actually use current locale and converts strings according to it.

See Rails 5.2.3 docs and sources for those methods:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate

So I cannot pass the locale to `parameterize` method directly. Then I should set the locale before my constant is defined.

Setting `I18n.default_locale = :de` inside `application.rb` file did not help. I already had that and the strings have been transliterated regardless.

What eventually helped was setting `I18n.locale = :de` manually. Thanks to this, I got my strings parameterized correctly without any changes to `MyConstant` definition.

Answer (score 4):

The `parameterize` method in Rails (through its use of [`ActiveSupport::Inflector#transliterate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate)) is in locale aware. It thus uses locale-depending rules to transliterate characters such as Umlauts to ASCII characters.

When your app handles a request (or at least once after booting), you are usually setting a I18n locale, e.g. with `I18n.locale = :de` for a single request or with `I18n.default_locale = :de` for your whole app. After that, Rails (resp. the i18n gem) used this locale by default for its transliteration rules.

When initially setting your constant, this default locale was likely not yet set. The i18n gem is thus not aware of the German transliteration rules and uses only the basic Unicode normalization rules.

As a workaround, you can either pass the desired locale to use to the parameterize method as

```
MY_CONSTANT = [
  'Breite in mm',
  'Höhe in mm',
  'Länge in mm'
].map { |const| const.parameterize(locale: :de).freeze }.freeze
```

or you can alternatively set the default i18n locale earlier than when your code is executed (e.g. in a file in `config/initializers`, depending on where exactly you initialize your constant):

```
I18n.default_locale = :de
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! Here's an upvote from me. Unfortunately, this works only in Rails 6 so I added an answer for Rails 5.